# Difference between graphic/display/screen AND video/movie resolutions?

Tags: video, display, resolution, high-definition

I am not well-versed with resolution when it comes to display/video, but I am very curious to know if there is any difference between resolution terminology of LCD/LED display/screen panels of television & computer monitors **and** that of video (movies)? If so, how does it exactly work?

Example: I am confused with resolutions like 1440p (2560x1440) which is used with displays and is known as QHD **VS** 2160p (3840 x 2160) which is used with videos (and images?) and is known as Ultra HD.

I am sorry if my question is unclear.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Better answer here.. and maybe yours is a duplicate :) http://superuser.com/questions/977654/what-is-the-difference-between-4k-uhd-and-qhd-do-we-agree-on-one-official-reso

Comment: Thanks, Alex. I will check it out. :) However, on first look the above question seems different to me than my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go down enough, eventually they'll all be referencing the number of pixels. The names (esp unclear ones like UltraHD) are now the realm of marketeers, and have long lost any useful meaning.  One thing you can generally see is that the resolutions for TV's will generally be 16:9 aspect ratio.

There is a decent list of resolutions, their names, and some history on this Wikipedia [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_display_resolution).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, I agree that it all boils down to pixels, but my main question is about the naming standard they are using for resolution in displays/screens and videos, which seems a bit different to me. Or do all the resolutions apply in the same way to all of these (displays, screens, videos, etc.)?

Comment: Yes, all the resolutions apply in the same way, they describe the panel (the actual display) in a TV or monitor or phone.  I think is probably just that for TV's you'll hear a lot fewer names, and they'll be more 'user' friendly.  One other thing that might have caught people out, for a while the vertical resolution was the key, 480, 720, 1080 etc.  But once we went past that you start hearing 2k, 4k and 8k, but though 2k still references the vertical resolution, 4k & 8k is the number of pixels (4x as many as hd)!!

Comment: Okay, but same applies for video/movie recordings too? Just reconfirming.

Comment: Yes, the resolution of digital recordings usually match tv resolutions due to their obvious relationship.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot for the answer, and also for being patient with me. :)